# Remove hours and minutes from dates in one step

Tags: excel, vba, date

I always get the dates like shown in **Column A**, but I need them as shown in column C. How can I do it without having to create **column B** helper? I need that because the hours and minutes mess up what I want to achieve after this.

**Column A**

Time with hours and minutes:

```
22/05/2015 14:57
11/06/2015 15:40
28/05/2015 08:27
26/05/2015 14:51
25/05/2015 14:18
25/05/2015 15:51
```

**Column C**

Time without hours and minutes:

```
22/05/2015 
11/06/2015 
28/05/2015 
26/05/2015
25/05/2015
25/05/2015
```

I managed to solve this by creating a column B that converts to text

```
=Text(A2;"DD-MM-AAAA")
```

and then column C converts text to value

```
=Data.value(B2)
```

While this process works, it causes me a lot of unnecessary data and I wonder if I can do this automatically with a [vba-excel](/questions/tagged/vba-excel) macro in one step. I also want the number dates in column C always equal to the number of dates in **column A** and dates in the same order.

Comment: Why not just re-format column **A** to hide the time ??

Comment: @findwindow good idea, but the LEFT function is used for _string_ manipulation so you would wrap it in a DATEVALUE function `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))`

Comment: @MacroMan I was just testing you =P

Comment: @findwindow I know, never doubted you for a second!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent guessing OP wants it in column C? Then again, copy/paste into C then format XD

Comment: @Gary'sStudent my guess is that the OP wants to deal with just the dates in other formulas without the need for < and > bracketing the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was tagged with [excel-vba] so I'll offer a full column time stripping solution.

The [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) makes quick work of stripping off the date portion of a datetime. The *fieldinfo* parameter can specify the DMY format you are using and discard the time portion with the appropriate [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018.aspx). While most TextToColumns commands are made 'in place', an alternate *destination* is available if specified. When specifying an alternate destination, the original data is left intact.

```
Option Explicit

Sub stripTime()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'check to see if A1 is a date or a column text label
        i = Abs(Not IsDate(.Cells(1, 1).Value))
        With .Range(.Cells(1 + i, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, "C"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, xlDMYFormat), Array(10, xlSkipColumn))
            'optionally assign a custom number format
            .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "[color10]dd-mmm-yyyy_)"
            'optionally autofit the column width
            .Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

After processing you are left with your original datetimes in column A and true date-only values in column C.

[image: strip_date_out_of_datetime]

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I asked for!

Comment: Be careful with rows.count, because it counts also formatted cells.

Answer (score 22):

To get the date only use:

```
=INT(A2)
```

And format to date.  This works because dates in excel are the number of days since December 31st, 1899 so for example May 10th, 2016 is 42500 days since.

And the Time is a decimal based on 24 hours. So, May 10th, 2016 12:00:00 equates to 42500.5.

So to get just the date we remove the decimal.  INT() does just that.

Comment: I feel outsmarted for not finding this :O. This is formula works perfect!

Comment: @carlos_cs we all have moments where we overthink the problem and make it more complicated than it needs to be.  Sometimes it takes others to help point out the easier method.

Comment: @carlos_cs lol _we_ all feel outsmarted with Scott ^_^; Edit: I shouldn't say we but _I_.

Comment: `=INT(NOW())` is returning "5/26/2016 0:00"?

Comment: @Adavid02 Now format the cell to show only the date and not the time.  Either using "Short Date" or a custom format of `m\d\yyy`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `=Today()` OR  `=NOW()` then change

Answer (score 0):

**10-04-2020 3:09:42 PM** transforms to **10.04.2020**

Using this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",TEXT(A1,"DD.MM.YYYY"))
```